# PHP array and Json decode errors

Tags: php, arrays, json

Please help as I have spent two days on this...

I have a JSON object. as shown below.

```
[{"attr":{"id":"node_8","rel":"folder"},"data":"_demo","state":"closed"},{"attr":        {"id":"node_13","rel":"folder"},"data":"demo3","state":""}][{"attr":{"id":"node_8","rel":"folder"},"data":"_demo","state":"closed"},{"attr":{"id":"node_13","rel":"folder"},"data":"demo3","state":""}]string(140) "[{"attr":{"id":"node_8","rel":"folder"},"data":"_demo","state":"closed"},{"attr":{"id":"node_13","rel":"folder"},"data":"demo3","state":""}]"
```

Using Json decode I get the following output..

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [attr] => Array ( [id] => node_8 [rel] => folder ) [data] => _demo [state] => closed ) [1] => Array ( [attr] => Array ( [id] => node_13 [rel] => folder ) [data] => demo3 [state] => ) ) aArray
```

How can I iterate through and access each value as a list so I can add div classes, and id's. For instance [id] => node_8. How can I access that value and convert it to div id = "node_8", or [rel] => folder, and convert to div class = "folder". For example I hope that makes sense
    for example

```
 foreach ($data as $key => $value){
    if(is_array($value)) {
    {

     echo $value . "<br />";
     }
    }
  }
```

which produces id = node_8 rel = folder data = _demo state = closed
id = node_13 rel = folder data = demo3 state =

I have added the answer below if anyone has problems with multi dimension arrays, and decoding from JSON, adding divs etc to the array. Kindly provided by Shayan Husaini.
Where $string is equal to array.

```
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);
foreach ($json_a as $value) {
```

echo '
';
      echo 'id: '.$value['attr']['id'];
      echo '
';
       echo 'rel: '.$value['attr']['rel'];
       echo '
';
       echo 'name: '.$value['data'];
       echo '
';
       echo '' .$value['state'];
       echo '';

Comment: i dont get the problem. why not use foreach?

Comment: Have you even bothered to read [php's tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php) or [the documentation about arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) ?

Comment: I would love to know what you have tried over the past two days

Comment: I have gone through every example for the for each array, I dont know how to append to each element in the array. I can extract the information, but I cant append anything to each individual element of the array. I hope that makes sense. for example foreach ($data as $key => $value){
if(is_array($value)) {
  {

  echo $value . "<br />";
  }
}
} which produces id = node_8 rel = folder data = _demo state = closed
id = node_13 rel = folder data = demo3 state =

Comment: Okay, good.  You've echoed out the values of the array.  What's your issue?

Comment: Hi Jack. I just need them in a list where I can add elements to the array. For instance enclose one of the array values in a div, another in an a tag. I have been looking further and my issue seems to be that  I cant access certain parts of the array. If i use echo($value["state"]);echo($value["data"]); that is ok. However I cant echo the id and rel tags. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is multidimensional array so you need to define the keys as well for child arrays to get the values. I hope this would help you:

```
foreach ($data as $value){
       echo 'id: '.$value['attr']['id'];
       echo 'rel: '.$value['attr']['rel'];
       echo 'demo: '.$value['demo'];
       echo 'state: '.$value['state'];
  }
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH Shayan. My computer was just to go through the window lol. echo 'id: '.$value['attr']['id']; was what I was looking for. I could not get that to display. You are an absolute star. Thank you for making the time to comment. I appreciate it so much as its 3 days I spent on this, and its something so simple, that you can spot straight away. Many many thanks again.